# Visual Studio Code - build Windows Phone on mac

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to build Windows Phone projects using the new IDE, Visual Studio Code, for Mac?

Not looking for actual developing at this point, only to build & test the project. Something like a `xbuild` alternative, maybe. Reason is we already have a cruise control running on a Mac and right now it's a pain to also build Windows Phone projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Visual Studio Code does not include any build tools, only an editor and debugging support for (currently) Node.js applications.

More information here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages